# How to loop through all the files located under a certain path in zsh?

Tags: for-loop, zsh, glob

Here's what I have so far:

```
for file in $(find /path/to/directory -type f); echo $file; done
```

but I get this error:

```
zsh: parse error near `done'
```

Comment: missing a `do` after the first ;

Answer (score 101, accepted):

There is no need to use `find`. You could try the following:

```
for file in /path/to/directory/**/*(.); do echo $file; done
```

or

```
for file in /path/to/directory/**/*(.); echo $file
```

- the `**` [pattern matches multiple directories recursively](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Roadmap.html#Pattern-Matching). So `a/**/b` matches any `b` somewhere below `a`. It is essentially matches the list `find a -name b` produces.
- `(.)` is a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) and tells *zsh* to only match plain files. It is the equivalent to the `-type f` option from `find`.
- you do not really need double quotes around `$file` because [*zsh* does not split variables into words on substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Roadmap.html#General-Comments-on-Syntax).
- the first version is the regular form of the `for`-loop; the second one is the [short form](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Alternate-Forms-For-Complex-Commands) without `do` *and* `done`

The reason for the error you get is due to the last point: when running a single command in the loop you need either both `do` and `done` or none of them. If you want to run more than one command in the loop, you must use them.

Comment: This prints an error if no files could be found. How would one disable that message?

Comment: @LarsNyström You can add `N` to the glob qualifier, e. g. `for file in /path/to/directory/**/*(N.); echo $file`. This sets the `NULL_GLOB` option for that pattern, which deletes the pattern from the argument list instead of reporting an error. So in case no matching files exist, the command would effectively be reduced to `for file in ; echo $file`.

Comment: Answer is a goldmine for leveraging great features in zsh.
Awesome explanation and referencing.

Comment: Dont forget to have `#!/bin/zsh` zsh as a first line in script

Comment: How to track a number at the same time?

Comment: @minseong If you want a counter that increases with each file you can just initalize a variable with 0 before the loop and use *arithmetic expansion* within the loop to do increase it for each file. For example: `counter=0; for file in dir/**/*(.); echo $(( ++counter )) $file`. `$(( ++counter))` first increases `$counter` by 1 and then expands to the result. (`$(( counter++ ))` on the other hand would expand to the current value of `$counter` and  increase it after.)

Answer (score 4):

Can you check if adding `""` around `$file` solves this problem like so:

```
for file in $(find /path/to/directory -type f); echo "$file"; done
```

Edit:

add `do` before `echo` and let me know if it solves the problem:

```
for file in $(find /path/to/directory -type f); do echo "$file"; done
```

Comment: In `zsh`, unlike in `bash`, wordsplitting is disabled by default (unless for some reason you set `sh_word_split`) and quoting variables has no effect.